# making sense of hom-set between chain complex and abelian group

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $\textbf C$ be a chain complex of right $R$-modules, let $A$ be a left $R$-module and let $B$ be an abelian group.

How to make sense of the $\mathrm{Hom}(\textbf {C}\otimes_R A,B)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_R(\textbf {C},\mathrm{Hom}(A,B))$?

Comment: Can you provide some more context?

Comment: Actually, $\text{Hom}(A,B)$ seems to be an $R$-module by defining $r \cdot f(x) := f(rx)$, so that part seems correct.

Comment: @Ruben $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ has a canonical right $R$-module structure induced by the left $R$-module structure on $A$: $(\xi r)(x)=\xi(rx)$ for $r\in R$, $x\in A$ and $\xi:A\to B$.

Comment: From your notation I would assume $\text{Hom}_R$ to mean *Hom sets of $R$-modules*, which would imply that we consider the Hom sets of individual objects from the complex. This certainly exists. Otherwise we could take it to mean *Hom sets of complexes of $R$-modules*, with $B$ for example taken as the complex with $B$ at zero and $0$ everywhere else. This comes down to morphisms $f : C_0 \to B$ such that the kernel contains the image of the map $C_1 \to C_0$ I think. There may be a third interpretation.

Comment: @FabioLucchini Exactly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if $\mathbf C$ denote a complex
$$\cdots\to C_n\xrightarrow{\gamma_n}C_{n+1}\to\cdots$$
then $\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\Hom(\mathbf C\otimes_RA,B)$ denote the complex
$$\cdots\leftarrow\Hom(C_n\otimes_RA,B)\xleftarrow{\Hom(\gamma_n\otimes_R1_A,1_B)}\Hom(C_{n+1}\otimes_RA,B)\leftarrow\cdots$$
while $\Hom(\mathbf C,\Hom(A,B))$ denote the complex:
$$\cdots\leftarrow\Hom_R(C_n,\Hom(A,B))\xleftarrow{\Hom_R(\gamma_n,\Hom(1_A,1_B))}\Hom_R(C_{n+1},\Hom(A,B))\leftarrow\cdots$$